# Can I call an action in another action (in a rails controller)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When an action in a controller has been called, can I then call another action from that action?

And what would happen if both actions have some template to render?

Comment: If one must do this, remember to put the called method behind `private`, unless it is a publicly-available route in its own right

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes you can, if it is in the same controller.

Calling `zoo` will provide the template for zoo with instances for `@x` and `@a`.  Neither foo or bar will be rendered.  If you have explicitly set a `render` method, then you might get a double render error, unless you `return` before the second render is called.

```
def foo
  @x = 1
end

def bar
  @a = 2
end

def zoo
  foo
  bar
end
```

Comment: if I explicitly set a render method in 'bar', then when 'zoo' is called, will it render bar's template (i.e. bar.html.erb) ?

Comment: Yes, but you will need to `return bar` in `zoo`, otherwise you will get a DoubleRender error.

You are probably better abstracting the shared logic between `bar` and `zoo` into a protected method.

Comment: @TheWho can I pass any extra parameters while calling foo and bar ? like foo, {user_id: 3}

Comment: @tusharh The methods for Rails controller actions don't take arguments. Actions being methods which map to a route, ie: `index`, `create`, `destroy`, etc.  Now, you could have private methods which do take params, and that is conventional to do so.

Comment: @TheWho Thanks for response, but I did figured out how to pass arguments in such cases, its simple because when calling 'foo' action from 'zoo' action all the params that zoo received will be send to 'foo' as well, so I have added my args in params like - params[:arg1] = "something" before calling 'foo', and they are accessible in 'foo' now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use redirect_to to call another action within your controller. To render one template inside another, you can use partials and/or layouts.

Comment: `redirect_to` doesn't call the other action (in the sense of method calling), it instead tells the browser to request the other action. Actions are just methods, which are called by `ActionController` when it's handling a request. They can be called from other actions as @TheWho shows.

Answer (score 0):

The Who is correct about how to call the actions, but if you are calling an action within an action you need to refactor your code to pull out the logic that does what you are trying to accomplish into its own action, then allowing each action to render its own template.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can do this. And if you might probably make a one layout nil so that it will display in your views in a nice way

say (this following example has the 'my_controller' as the layout)

```
class my_controller < application_controller 

   def my_parent_method
     @text_from_my_child_method = child_method
   end 

   def child_method
     return 'hello from child_method'
     render :layout => false #here we are making the child_method layout false so that it #will not effect the parent method
   end

end
```

and in your 'my_parent_method.rhtml' (view) you can use the variable

```
<%= @text_from_my_child_method %> and it should print 'hello from child_method'
```

hope this helps

cheers,
sameera

Comment: The `render` will never be called in `child_method`. You're `return`ing out of the method before the `render` line is executed. Are you trying to show that the `child_method` won't render a view? (That could be made concrete by declaring `child_method` as `private`.)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do it because there's some sort of common code in both actions maybe it's better to refactor this code into a before_filter.