# Persisting ActiveRecord objects between requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I have an ActiveRecord model named `Document` and have implemented CRUD operations around it. I just have a problem with persisting a `Document` instance between requests when validation fails (be cause I wanna redirect to another page when this happens).

First, I tried storing the instance in the flash session:

```
# documents_controller.rb

def new
  @document = flash[:document] || Document.new
end

def create
  document = Document.new(document_params)
  if document.save
    return redirect_to documents_path
  end
  flash[:document] = document
  redirect_to new_document_path
end
```

With the code above, I was expecting that the actual `Document` instance was stored in the flash session, but instead it became a string which looks somewhat like `#<Document:0xad32368>`. After searching online for a while, I found out that for some reasons you cannot store ActiveRecord objects in sessions.

There are a lot of suggestions about just storing the object's `id` in the flash session, but I can't do that because as you can see, the object is not yet stored in the database.

Next, I tried reconstructing the `Document` instance after the redirect, taking advantage of the instance's `attributes` method (which returns a serializeable hash that can be stored in the session):

```
# documents_controller.rb

def new
  @document = Document.new(flash[:document_hash] || {})
end

def create
  ...
  flash[:document_attributes] = document.attributes
  redirect_to new_document_path
end
```

This almost solved the problem, except for the part in which the validation errors (`document.errors`) are not preserved. Also, if this is used to persist an instance already stored in the database (in the case of failed validations when updating a `Document` instance), I'm not sure which between the original attributes and the new attributes will get persisted.

Right now I've already run out ideas to try. Anyone who has a decent solution for this?

**EDIT:**

You might be wondering why I still have to redirect to another page instead of just rendering the new document view template or the `new` action in the `create` method. I did so because there are some things in my views that are dependent on the current controller method. For example, I have a tab which needs to be highlighted when you are on the document creation page (done by checking if `action_name == "new" and controller_name == "documents"`). If I do:

```
def create
  ...
  render action: "new"
end
```

the tab will not get highlighted because `action_name` will now be `create`. I also can't just add additional condition to highlight the tab if `action_name == "create"` because documents can also be created from the the index page (`documents_path`). Documents can also be updated from the index page (`documents_path`) or from the detail page (`document_path(document)`), and if validation fails in the `update` method, I'd like to redirect to the previous page.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure why you're doing it the way you are, but maybe check out the documentation of caching and storing the data in there between requests. Just remember to set the timeout so you don't run into problems. 

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/Store.html

Comment: @Anti-Fun According the the ActiveSupport Cache documentation, `ActiveSupport::Cache::Store can store any serializable Ruby object.`. And the reason why ActiveRecord objects can't be stored in sessions is because of some serialization issues. So I guess (not sure, haven't tried yet) caching the ActiveRecord object will still store it as a string?

Comment: Cache marshals objects (so can serialize nearly anything) whereas sessions (as of 4.1) use json by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

I was able to make a workaround for it using `ActiveSupport::Cache::Store` (as suggested by @AntiFun). First I created a `fake_flash` method which acts closely like the flash sessions except that it uses the cache to store the data, and it looks like this:

```
def fake_flash(key, value)
  if value
    Rails.cache.write key, value
  else
    object = Rails.cache.read key
    Rails.cache.delete key
    object
  end
end
```

And then I just used it like the flash session.

```
# documents_controller.rb

def new
  ...
  @document = fake_flash[:document] || Document.new
  ...
end

def create
  document = Document.new document_params
  ...
  # if validation fails
  fake_flash :document, document
  redirect_to new_document_page
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If I really need to fake persisting something between requests (all of the variables that you set are lost between requests), I will ususally put the relevant attributes into hidden fields in the new form.

In your case, this is overkill. In your code, you are redirecting, which causes a new request:

```
def create
  document = Document.new(document_params)
  if document.save
    return redirect_to documents_path
  end
  flash[:document] = document
  redirect_to new_document_path
end
```

You can easily render the output of another action, instead of redirecting, by using `render action: 'action_to_render'`. So in your example, this would probably be:

```
def create
  @document = Document.new(document_params)
  if @document.save
    render action: 'index'
  else
    render action: 'new'
  end
end
```

Which can be simplified to:

```
def create
  @document = Document.new(document_params)
  action_to_render = @document.save ? 'index' : 'new'
  render action_to_render
end
```

If you need extra logic from the action, you can refactor the logic to a method called from both actions, or simply [call the other action from the current one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710677/can-i-call-an-action-in-another-action-in-a-rails-controller).

It is fine once in a while, but I would caution that having to jerk around with the rendering too much is usually indicative of poor architecture.

**Edit:**

An additional option, given the newly highlighted constraints, could be to make the new and create methods the same. Remove the `new` action and routes, and make create answer for GET and PATCH requests. The action might look something like:

```
def create
  @document = Document.new(document_params)
  request.patch? && @document.save && redirect_to( documents_path )
end
```

I actually use something very similar to this for almost all of my controllers, as it tends to DRY things significantly (as you can remove the extra probably identical view, as well)

Another option would be to just use an instance variable to keep track of the active tab in this instance, and make the rest of the code a lot cleaner.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am well aware about using the `render` method to render a different action or view template, but as I said in my question (I apologize in case it's not that clear), I can't use this way because some elements in my views are dependent on the current action. For example, I have tabs which needs to be highlighted when the current action is `new` (retrieved using `action_name`), but if I call `render action: 'new'` from the `create` method, the value of `action_name` will be `create`, making the tab not highlighted.

Comment: Did you see my edit of "If you need extra logic from the action, you can refactor the logic to a method called from both actions, or simply call the other action from the current one."? The tab highlighting would have been a good thing to include in the OP.

Comment: Okay I will edit my question to include that. Thanks.

Comment: @Arnelle Balane - see edit. Do not overlook first line, either. Usually best for multi-step forms and the like, but may be relevant here. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions but that's not exactly what I wanted for now. It will take a lot of changes in my current codebase. I will take note of these though, might be useful in the days to come. Thanks.